# For which key length (as a function of file size) is a XOR cipher considered as safe?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

It is well-known that, [doing a XOR of a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) against a **short key** is highly insecure encryption (can be broken with frequency analysis).

But if the length of the key is equal to (or has same order of magnitude than) the length of the file to be encrypted, then the situation is close to a [one-time-pad / Vernam cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) and it is secure (no frequency analysis can be done).

Is there a rule of thumb for which XOR cipher is generally considered as safe?

e.g.:

- `key size = file size` => super safe, [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)
- `key size = (1/2) file size` => looks really really safe, I don't see how a freq analysis could work with only 4 repetitions
- `key size = (1/100) file size` => ?
- `key size = (1/10000) file size` => ?

Let's say the file is 10 GB if it helps to get the order of magnitudes.

---

Example with `key size = (1/2) file size`:

```
file:       0101 0111    (size 8)
key:        0100 0100    (0100, i.e. size 4, repeated twice)

cyphertext: 0001 0011
```

Here the key `0100` is repeated twice. How could someone having **only the size-8 cyphertext and knowledge of the fact the key is of size 4** break it?

Comment: to answer the bold question: they wouldn't, unless some of the text was known. If you know that a key repeats exactly once, and you know part of the file contents (EXIF, headers, BOM, etc), you can tell exactly what's on the other part of the CT keyed by the same offset. Contextually expanding those areas allows crawling beyond the duplicated materials. You can also use file format analysis to eliminate options, like a missing reserved char in a run of binary data.

Comment: to answer the title's question, the percentage is 100%.

Answer (score 4):

It’s not just frequency analysis. If you reuse any part of a key that’s being XORed, an attacker just has to XOR the two ciphertexts with each other, and the key drops out entirely and you get the same result as XORing the two plaintexts with each other, which is pretty easy to decode.

A xor K xor B xor K = A xor B xor K xor K = A xor B, since K xor K will always be null.

Comment: So even with `keylength = filesize / 2`, you claim that it can be broken? If so could you provide an example with filesize = 10? (would help a lot for getting the idea!)

Comment: @Basj http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html

Comment: @Basj - Real cryptographers use very conservative definitions of "broken". Try a search for "IND-CPA" and "IND-CCA" for examples. Reusing even a single bit of key material in an XOR cipher will render it insecure by the IND-CPA criterion. Using XOR at all (without a MAC) is already insecure by the IND-CCA criterion.

Comment: @MikeScott. I'm skeptical about how it could be broken in the case `keylength = filesize / 2`. I updated question with an example. Can you explain how an attacker could break it? (you said it's not frequency analysis but something else)

Comment: @Nemo Interesting, can you post this as an answer and maybe give an example (see updated question with example at the end) of how it could be broken with `keylength = filesize / 2`?

Comment: Here's a simple example: say the attacker knows nearly all of the contents of the encrypted file, but doesn't know the value of the first N bytes and wants to learn that. (Maybe the encrypted file is a forwarded email, and the attacker knows the original email and wants to know who the email was forwarded to, etc.) The attacker can XOR the first N bytes of the ciphertext with the first N bytes of the second half of the ciphertext and then XOR that with what he knows the first N bytes of the second half of the plaintext is. The result will be the first N bytes of the plaintext.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer @AgentME? I'm sure that it's very clear and simple once you know it, but before knowing it, it's hard to grasp without an example.

Comment: @AgentME Also it seems that you add an additional assumption: the fact that you know **both**  cyphertext and plaintext for some part of the file, which is not true in my original question. In your case, of course, yes, if you know both, I understand the key can be cracked.

Comment: My example was just one extreme simple case. There's plenty of realistic cases like it. For example, many files have lots of null bytes. By XORing the two halves of the ciphertext together, everywhere that was a null byte in one half of the plaintext results in a byte of plaintext. Any type of regular pattern in the file (such as the predictable frequencies of english ASCII characters or formatting data from many popular file formats) can be similarly exploited. An encryption scheme that is only safe for completely unpredictable/random plaintexts is not good and very far from state of the art.

Comment: @Basj An attacker will _often_ know part of the plaintext. Here's an example for you. Suppose the plaintext you're encrypting is "From: Basj\nTo:Mike Scott:\nSet off the bomb now". Since the attacker can easily guess the first half of the text, because he already knows it's a message from you to me, he can decrypt the important part.

Comment: Ok @AgentME this totally makes sense, that's right. Thanks. Would you compile your 2 comments into an answer (it totally answers the question, with the null bytes part, etc.)